# How to activate dropdowns: Click below 768px width on one element and hover above 768px on a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click, responsive

I need a menu to open when I am hovering over a div when above 768px window width, and the menu also to open when I click a span when below 768px window width (this span is hidden above mobile). I keep having problems where the click, or hover, carries over between the two screen sizes (0-768px and 769 and up).

[I set up a jsfiddle with an example of what I have so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/21dpoawt/)

And here is the jQuery I am using:

```
function subNavDropdowns(width){
   if (width <= 767) {
      $('span').click(function(e) {
         $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').removeClass('visible');
         $(this).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('visible');
         e.stopPropagation()
      });
   } else {
      $('div').hover(function(f) {
         $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').removeClass('visible');
         $(this).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('visible');
         f.stopPropagation()
      });
   }
}
$(function () {
   var onLoadWidth = $(window).width();
   subNavDropdowns(onLoadWidth);
   $(window).resize(function () {
      var resizeWidth = $(window).width();
      subNavDropdowns(resizeWidth);
   });
})
```

I solved this issue before (hover on desktop, and click on mobile) by adding function(e) and e.stopPropagation(), but they were always when the hover/click was on the same element. Now that I'm trying to do it on a click for a span on mobile, and a hover for a div on desktop, I am having issues.

Comment: This may not solve your problem entirely but for good measure I'd make sure to put your function in your `$(document).ready()` since your dealing with elements that will be loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There's one big problem with your code: you're attaching new event listeners on every resize event. I'd suggest splitting up the code differently.

First, let's single out the functions that show and hide your menus:

```
var showCurrentMenu = function() {
  // Hide other menus:
  $(this).parent().children()
    .siblings("ul").addClass("visible");

  // Show closest menu
  $(this).siblings("ul").addClass("visible");
};
```

Then, create an accessible variable that holds the window width, and create a method to set it:

```
var lastWindowWidth = 0;
var setWindowWidth = function() {
  lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();
}
```

Now that we have all the methods we need, we can initialize the event listeners *once*.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(setWindowWidth);

  var mobileBtns = $("span");
  var desktopBtns = $("div");

  mobileBtns.click(showCurrentMenu);
  desktopBtns.hover(showCurrentMenu);


  // Initialize first window width:
  setWindowWidth();

});
```

If you just hide your `<span>`s or `<div>`s using css media breakpoints, there's no need to disable the event listeners. If you *do* want to disable them, here's how you can:

```
mobileBtns.off("click", showCurrentMenu);
desktopBtns.off("hover", showCurrentMenu);
```

Comment: That's very interesting, and thank you for showing me how to split up my code better! It is very clean. I never knew about .off() before. Could come in handy in the future. I'll see how this works out, thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to fix your problem, as long as you make sure you _do not_ attach multiple event listeners inside _other_ event listeners by accident (by e.g. `.click` or `.hover` or `.on`). Let me know if you need more help.